# Find a record with ALL associations having a certain value

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, associations

This is more an SQL question, but I try to solve this in Rails:

I have an `User` who `has_many :days`. Days have a `status` which can be *available* or *booked*. I want to find all users who have **only available days**. I use:

```
User.includes(:days).where.not(days: { status: 'booked' }).references(:days)
```

The generated SQL query looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM "users" LEFT OUTER JOIN "days" ON "days"."user_id" = "users"."id" WHERE ("days"."status" != 'booked')
```

The results contain users which have both kind of statuses.
Thanks for any idea how to solve this!

Comment: No idea how to do it in rails, but the query needs to be more like this: `SELECT * FROM users WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT user_id FROM days WHERE status = 'booked')`

Comment: What do you mean by "who have only available days"? Do you want users who are available for a given day (or set of days) or users who have no booked days at all?

Comment: @max I try to find users who are available on all days. I will combine this will a ```.where(dated: from..too)``` scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@CptMisery answered it correctly. The Rails syntax looks like this:

`User.where.not(id: Day.select(:user_id).distinct.where(status: 'booked'))`

Answer (score 3):

> I want to find all users who have only available days.

For this type of things you should use [`joins`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/joins):

```
User.joins(:days).where(days: { status: 'available' }).group('users.id')
```

The generated SQL will look something like this:

```
SELECT users.* FROM users INNER JOIN days ON days.user_id = users.id WHERE days.status = available
```

## EDIT

If I misunderstood you, and status in not either `"booked"` or `"available"` (but, for example, can be blank or `nil`), then the query should be as you had it with `where.not`:

```
User.joins(:days).where.not(days: { status: 'booked' }).group('users.id')
```

## EDIT2

to get users with available days and without booked ones I'd probably do:

```
User.joins(:days).where.not(days: { status: 'booked' }).where(days: { status: 'available' }).group('users.id')
```

Comment: `User.joins(:days).where.not(days: { status: 'booked' })`

Comment: @max from the question I (somehow) concluded that `status` is only 'booked' or 'available'. But you're right, we have to be precise while answering.

Comment: Won't this return any user who has *at least* one day which is not 'booked'? The original question asked how to find "all users who have *only* available days"

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The result is several times the same user (which could be prevented by ```.distinct```). As @gmcnaughton already stated, I try to find users who are available at **all days**. Any ideas?

Comment: @Railsana adding grouping by users.id would solve the same user appearing twice. As to status - you can query for both at the same time, let me edit the answer.

Comment: @AndreyDeineko Thanks for the update. This still shows users who have *available* days, but also *booked* days. I try to find users where **every days is available**.

Comment: @Railsana `User.joins(:days).where.not('days.status != booked AND days.status = available').group('users.id')` and with this?

Comment: Sorry, this returns all users that have **at least one** non-booked day, but it doesn't check **all days**. I answered my own question with the help of @CptMisery.